# AppleScript: How to get the character count of an .rtf file?

Tags: applescript, text, internationalization

I would like an AppleScript .scpt file to determine the character count of any given .rtf file. I'm not sure if this is standard for character counts, but I would like each space character (" ") to also count as one character.

I would like the script to accomplish this, without actually opening the file in TextEdit.

It is important to note that this is a rich text file, not a simple plain text (.txt) file. This fact complicates things. It is not as simple as chopping off the rich text header, because a single .rtf file may contain multiple different types of rich text formatting.

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked, "What is the best way to go about this?" and while I'll not make that determination, nonetheless, here's an example using the `do shell script` command and some command line utilities.

```
set theRichTextFile to quoted form of "/path/to/filename.rtf"
set theCharacterCount to do shell script "textutil -stdout -convert txt " & theRichTextFile & " | LANG=en_US.UTF-8 wc -m | sed 's/ //g'"
```

Note that `theRichTextFile` must be a quoted POSIX pathname.

Update: Per comment by @jackjr300, added `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` to the command.

Comment: Note : The `Locale` is not defined in any shell when you use the `do shell script` command,
So, the `wc` command count all ASCII character in any composed character.
Example : the RTF file contains "**Здравствуйте!**" (a Russian word), the `wc` command return **25** (ASCII characters).
To get the correct number, set the `LANG` to some lang.. with the **UTF-8**, like this :  `do shell script "textutil -stdout -convert txt '/path/of/someFile.rtf' |  LANG=en_US.UTF-8 wc -m | sed 's/ //g'"` --> now, the `wc` command return **13** (characters)